# How I can Iterate into SUM result from doctrine query

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I need some help about iterate over result in doctrine. This is my code for query:

```
$consulta = $em->createQuery('
SELECT bcr, SUM(bcr.volumenAlmacenado) as vol, SUM(bcr.pesoAlmacenado) as pes 
FROM ResiduoBundle:BodegaContieneResiduo bcr 
WHERE bcr.fechaIngreso BETWEEN :fechaP AND :fechaA AND bcr.fechaRetiro IS NULL 
GROUP BY bcr.idResiduo
'); 
        $consulta->setParameter('fechaA', $fechaActual);
        $consulta->setParameter('fechaP', $fechaPasada);
        return $consulta->getResult();
```

When I run in mysql return without problem. in symfony also get results. Now, when I tried to loop in twig I can't do, I think could be for my agregate functions in my query. I hope you can get me a clue or something about this. Grettings

Comment: You are most likely receiving mixed result. In this case when you iterate over your result-set, you should access first key of each element `row[0]` for instance, which holds the actual object. The rest of the keys represents the alias of your aggregate functions.

Comment: you could use {{ dump(entities) }} to debug what is inside

Answer (score 0):

You should added extension of mysql function SUM then you can use SUM function in doctrine query 
another way you can direct execute your query or native query of doctrine
Try following query you can get result

```
$consulta = $em->executeQuery('SELECT bcr, SUM(bcr.volumenAlmacenado) as vol, SUM(bcr.pesoAlmacenado) as pes FROM ResiduoBundle:BodegaContieneResiduo bcr WHERE bcr.fechaIngreso BETWEEN :fechaP AND :fechaA AND bcr.fechaRetiro IS NULL GROUP BY bcr.idResiduo'), 
        array('fechaA'=> $fechaActual, 'fechaP' => $fechaPasada));
        return $consulta->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use native query of doctrine

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addEntityResult('ResiduoBundle:BodegaContieneResiduo', 'bcr');
$rsm->addFieldResult('bcr', 'idResiduo', 'idResiduo');
$rsm->addFieldResult('bcr', 'volumenAlmacenado', 'vol');
$rsm->addFieldResult('bcr', 'pesoAlmacenado', 'pes');

$sqlQuery = "SELECT bcr.idResiduo as idResiduo, SUM(bcr.volumenAlmacenado) as vol, SUM(bcr.pesoAlmacenado) as pes
        FROM ResiduoBundle:BodegaContieneResiduo bcr
        WHERE bcr.fechaIngreso BETWEEN :fechaP AND :fechaA
        AND bcr.fechaRetiro IS NULL 
        GROUP BY bcr.idResiduo";
$query = $em->createNativeQuery($sqlQuery, $rsm)
     ->setParameter('fechaA', $fechaActual);
     ->setParameter('fechaP', $fechaPasada);
$query->getResult();
```

Comment: I run your code but now trows error. `Value for :BodegaContieneResiduo not found in params array. Params array key should be "BodegaContieneResiduo"`. Do you have some clue about the problem? I saw documentation in [doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) but it's show same as you put in your answer.

Comment: I have update query... Please try this one.. and let me know if have face issue

Comment: Welcome Rodrigo Diaz, Any kind of query related to symfony2 framework you can ask my directly on my E-mail : ashok.chitroda@gmail.com or skype id : ashok.chitroda